# Creating file and intermediate directories if does not exist

Tags: java, file, jakarta-ee, file-io, java-io

I want to create a file if and only if  that file does not exist.

As an example file location is referring to "C:\user\Desktop\dir1\dir2\filename.txt"

```
if (!file.exists()) {
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {                  
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the above code is failing, as the `dir1` and `dir2` does not exist.

For my case

- Sometime the dir1 and dir2 may exist and sometime they may not exist.
- I do not want to overwrite the contents of these intermediate directories if they already exists,

How to check this cleanly?

I was thinking to add the following check to handle this condition:

```
if (!file.getParentFile().getParentFile().exists()) {
    file.getParentFile().getParentFile().mkdirs();
}
if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
    file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
}

if (!file.exists()) {                               
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

Or there is a clearer solution than this?

Comment: You don't need to check `exists()`. `mkdirs()` will create directory only if it doesn't exists.

Comment: What will happen if the directory already exists and I am invoking mkdirs() again?

Comment: It will skip that. It won't create a new directory. Check the doc of that method. It clearly mentions this thing.

Comment: The doc only mentions - true if and only if the directory was created, along with all necessary parent directories; false otherwise

Comment: Re-Docs - *Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.*

Comment: *Why* do you want to create an empty file if and only if it doesn't exist? If this is some kind of preamble to creating a `FileOutputStream` or `FileWriter,` the only part that's necessary is the `mkdirs()` part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do something of this sort:

`file.getParentFile().mkdirs();`

> Creates the directory named by this abstract pathname, including any necessary but nonexistent parent directories. Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories.

**Update**

```
if (file.getParentFile().exists || file.getParentFile().mkdirs()){
        try
        {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
} else {
  /** could not create directory and|or all|some nonexistent parent directories **/
}
```

Comment: I already mentioned about this in my solution. So this is not an answer.

Comment: The code posted by user1631616 is not correct. file.getParentFile().mkdirs() will return false for the case when directory is already there. This can be also verified from the doc. The doc mentions - `true if and only if the directory was created, along with all necessary parent directories; false otherwise`.

Comment: @Baishakh yes you are correct it will only return true in case when directory was created. i have added check on existence. to your edit blindly doing `file.getParentFile().mkdirs()` is a bad practice as it still can fail to create all directories

Comment: Ok. In that case it boils down to the exists() checking after the mkdirs() call?

Comment: @Baishakh Repetition does not make this not an answer.  If you think it is incorrect, then down-vote, not flag.

Comment: The modification to this post by user pat has greatly changed the logic of this answer and should have been mentioned in a comment instead. @user1631616, you may want to review his changes in the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that `File.exists()` checks for the existence of a file *or* directory.

Instead of:

```
if(!file.exists()) {                               
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

You should explicitly check if the file is a file as there may be a directory of the same name:

```
if(!file.isFile()) {                               
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

Similarly, you should check that the parent file is a directory:

```
if (!file.getParentFile().getParentFile().isDirectory()) { ... }
```