# How to execute mkdir command of unix using Runtime.exec()?

Tags: java, unix

How to execute mkdir command of unix using Runtime.exec()? I Need to create a sub-directory in a specific directory structure using mkdir unix command through java code.

Comment: mkdir with 'p' flag... e.g. mkdir -p /opt/test/{sub-dir} , this command will create the whole set of directories, if they do not exist.

Comment: Do you want to know how to execute `mkdir`, or how to create a directory?

Comment: This question suffers from the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should ask "how to create the whole directory path (even if parent directory doesn't exist) in Java".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating file and intermediate directories if does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708229/creating-file-and-intermediate-directories-if-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 new File("directory path").mkdir();
```

or

```
 new File("directory path").mkdirs();//create parent directories
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String dirPath = "wlsdomain\app\user\mydir"
File directory = new File(dirPath); 
directory.mkdirs();
```

you have to use `mkdirs()` api I will create all the elements that do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation about `Process.class`

```
import java.io.IOException;


public class Mkdir {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        //The magic is here...
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mkdir /path/to/subdirectory/test");
        System.out.println("DONE");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are other ways like using the File method file.mkdir() but I think this is what you were looking for. Obviously if you are making a subdirectory you should use absolute path name.